# Integral Domain proof zero divisiors trouble.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Show that $\mathbb {Z} [\sqrt2] $ is an integral domain. 
i got everything but no zero divisiors. 
i would like to prove it directly by expanding $ (a+b \sqrt 2) * (c+d\sqrt 2) =0 $ and showing that this expression is zero iff a and b are zero or c and d are zero.

i tried asking at my university's math help center but neither of the math students or myself could get it and my prof isn't available.
i got close by expanding then stating that the terms with sums of root 2 =0 and the terms without also equaled zero. i then sumed the two expressions and factored to get something very close to what i wanted but still was a by cases argument.

Thanks, for the help.

Comment: Hint: $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}] \subset \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Yeah thats cheating thats my prof did in class.

Comment: one can make an argument that the reals are an ordered field then use the fact the $ Z \sqrt 2 $ is a subset of the reals since R has no zero divisors its subset cannot contain zero divisors.

Comment: How is that cheating?

Comment: It's the answer to a question I didn't ask?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that $a+b\sqrt{2}$ is a non-zero element of $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]$ and $c+d\sqrt{2}$ is another element of $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]$ such that $(a+b\sqrt{2})(c+d\sqrt{2})=0$. We would like to show that $c+d\sqrt{2}=0$, i.e. that $c=0$ and $d=0$.

Since $a+b\sqrt{2}\neq 0$, at least one of $a,b$ is non-zero. This implies that $n=a^2-2b^2\neq 0$: this is clear if $a=0$ and $b\neq 0$ or if $a\neq 0$ and $b=0$. And if $a,b\neq 0$, then $a^2-2b^2=0$ would imply that $\sqrt{2}$ is a rational number.

Therefore multiplying $(a+b\sqrt{2})(c+d\sqrt{2})=0$ by $a-b\sqrt{2}$, we get $ nc+nd\sqrt{2}=0$, which implies that $nc=0$ and $nd=0$. Therefore $c=d=0$ since $n\neq 0$ and $\mathbb{Z}$ is an integral domain.

Comment: very clever argument thank you.